# How to run python module andrewning/sortphotos in Windows

Tags: python, image-processing

Installed and ran this python module: https://github.com/andrewning/sortphotos

- Windows 8 + Python 3.4
- Module installed successfully
- Both folders exist and 'origin' contains the images

**My command**

```
python sortphotos.py -r D:\image-test\origin D:\image-test\destination
```

**Error**

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified

**Question:**

How to run this module properly in Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

On windows put "\\" instead of "\" and it should work.

```
python sortphotos.py -r D:\\image-test\\origin D:\\image-test\\destination
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however this does not work for me, the error remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just went down this path. There are a few things to do in order for this to work on windows. They are:

1) You must have Perl installed. I got it by installing Github for windows. However you choose to get Perl, make sure that perl.exe is on your PATH.

2) You can't use Python v2. I've now had to install both, and then make sure that python2 is on my PATH.

A bit of a pain that these dependencies aren't explained, but I gotta say that the script really does work great once you get past that.

NOTE: I did not have to replace "\" with "\" as Neko advised. I think that issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1 - Put your source and destination locations in quotes.

```
python sortphotos.py -r "D:\image-test\origin" "D:\image-test\destination"
```

2 - Make sure you're in the directory where `sortphotos.py` resides

```
%Folderpath%\sortphotos-master\src
```